# access ComboBox not changing when RowSource is changed

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an Access Combobox (or rather, a set of comboboxes) which is being populated through a SQL query in it's RowSource property.  This is all well and good, but just recently, the Combobox has stopped responding to changes in the RowSource value. I can check the query in SQL view and verify that the changes are occurring, but the combobox's values stay the same.  I have even cleared the Combobox's RowSource value entirely, and yet it still shows the same values.  I have no explanation for this voodoo combobox.

I have saved, exited, and reopened access, and still no changes to the voodoobox values.

Comment: Can you add some code of what you're trying?

Comment: I see the same in Access 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all else fails, try a Compact/Repair on the database.
Also, delete the combobox and recreate.